# Why does Spring Boot have two different ReactiveX implementations?

Tags: spring-boot, rx-java2, project-reactor

Spring Boot has two different dependencies that each implement [the same API](http://reactivex.io/): [Project Reactor](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core) and [RxJava 2](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava).  You can verify the dependencies in spring boot [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/383da2183eb00a3d16b51652e6caadb858f236ce/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml#L151).  So why the duplication?

Is there a reason to use one over the other in practice?

Comment: note Reactor doesn't implement the ReactiveX API, but is very close to RxJava2 both in the API design (at least compared to  `Flowable`) and the implementation design. Both follow the [Reactive Streams specification](http://www.reactive-streams.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind this is not a direct and mandatory dependency, but **a BOM that curates which versions are preferred and work well for this version of Spring Boot**. If you don't use RxJava2 (or a Spring project that explicitly does), you won't pull-in the dependency. If you do, and you don't specify a version, you'll pull in the one from that link.

**Now, why `RxJava2` AND `Reactor` you ask?** Spring Framework's `WebFlux` stack is built on top of Reactor, but Spring has always been about *choice*. Since RxJava2 and Reactor both implement the [`Reactive Streams` specification](http://www.reactive-streams.org/), they are interoperable. So if you prefer you user code to deal with RxJava2 types (or even RxJava 1 types), Spring will do the conversion for you.

**The plumbing is still done using Reactor**, and thus it is the preferred implementation for you to use as well, but it is up to you.